# Advanced combinatorial probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

There are $5$ rooms $R_1,R_2,R_3, R_4, R_5$ in a hallway. $17$ people may enter any of those $5$ rooms upon their wish. What is the probability that $5$ of them will enter $R_1$, $2$ will enter $R_2$, $4$ will enter $R_3$, $4$ will enter $R_4$  and  $2$  will enter $R_5$?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Are we to assume that each branch is equally likely to be chosen?

Comment: Please use dollar symbol $ to write mathematical expressions or numbers. Also show your primary effort.

Comment: Yes @user37344.

Comment: @MujibShena71 you should put more effort when you ask a question.

Comment: @MujibShena71 dont you think that answer is correct ?

Answer (score 1):

There is $17$ people but we should select $5 $people among them to place the first room.Then , we have $12$ people and we shoul select $2$ people among them.(I assume you know that combination i used for selecting objects in a set ) This process will continue until it is done.

Let come to the case of $5^{17}$ . It is said that each people can choose any of the rooms ,so the first person has $5 $ choice to get in a room and the second has also $5$ choice and so on ,i.e,  $5....5=5^{17}$

$\frac{C(17,5)C(12,2)C(10,4)C(6,4)C(2,2)}{5^{17}}$

Comment: Where's the 5 to the power 17 coming from?

Comment: A word or 2 of explanation would have improved this answer.

Comment: Agreed @kimchilover

Comment: @MujibShena71 is it okay now ?

Answer (score 0):

Assume that the rooms are filled **sequentially** with the desired number of people from oldest to youngest, say, then

$Pr = (\frac 1{5})^5\cdot(\frac 1{5})^2\cdot(\frac1{5})^4\cdot(\frac 1{5})^4\cdot(\frac 1{5})^2 = (\frac1{5})^{17}$

But actually it can be filled in any order, hence use permutations with repetitions to get

$Pr = \left(\dfrac 1 5\right)^{17}\times\dfrac{17!}{ 5!2!4!4!2!}$

Comment: permutating room assignment does not make sense to me. Is this question like distinguishable object to distinguishable box ?For ex , how many ways are there to disribute 17 cards to the first player given 5 cards the second player given 2 cards so on.

Comment: @leonard: Quite right, that's what happens when burning the midnight oil, reformulated !

Comment: @potato_man: +1 for the initial short and sweet ans !